# Regular Expression: Only convert url "http|https" outside element

Tags: html, regex

I have a string:

```
http://localhost/xyz
http://localhost/rpq
http://localhost/abc
<img src="http://localhost/xyz/image.png">
```

Now, I want to convert only:

```
http://localhost/xyz
http://localhost/rpq
http://localhost/abc
```

to link url, but not convert `<img src="http://localhost/xyz/image.png">` to link url.
Can you help me this problem with regular expression, please. Thank you so much.

Comment: with `^` you can ensure that http|https has to be at the beginning of to string to be matched, e.g. `/^(http|https)?/` etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5528593

Answer (score 1):

You can use ^ to specify http/ https in the start of the sentence.
For example:

```
^(?:http|https)\:\/\/.+
```

Comment: I have just try your way. But result only get first url

Comment: The regex is correct but you need to write some code to extract from the text. Have a look on https://regex101.com/r/ZTKxWp/1 which provide code to get the urls with different language.

Comment: Thankyou so much. But I can't match 2 url in a line. Example: [link](https://regex101.com/r/ZTKxWp/2). Can you help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can using the group function to find all text matched in a line. Example: https://regex101.com/r/ZTKxWp/3

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by `DOMParser()`:

```js
var text = `<img src="http://localhost/xyz/image.png">`;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
console.log(htmlDoc.querySelector("img").src);
```

```js
var text = `http://localhost/xyz
http://localhost/rpq
http://localhost/abc
<img src="http://localhost/xyz/image.png">`;
console.log(text.split("\n").map(function (v){return v.match(/^http/) ? v : getimgsrc(v);}).join("\n"));
function getimgsrc(text){
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
return htmlDoc.querySelector("img").src;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to answer is regex because my string is not only that but also it have type. This question is a type which links spilit by \n